# PostgreSQL: get value of object inside jsonb array for full text search

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

How do I get a certain value based on a key inside an object that is part of my array? I store my json data as jsonb inside my Postgres 9.6 DB

```
addresses (JSONB)
---------
[{"address":"abc@def.com", "type": "home"}, {"address":"xyz@def.com", "type": "work"}]
```

What I'd love to do is something like:

```
SELECT addresses ->> 'address' FROM foo
```

and then use the result in a full text search, where I search for a specific email-address like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE 
to_tsvector('simple', CAST(addresses ->>'address' as text)) @@ to_tsquery('abc:*');
```

All I get when I run the first query is: `(NULL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unnest the json array using [`jsonb_array_elements():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
with foo(addresses) as (
values
    ('[{"address":"abc@def.com", "type": "home"}, {"address":"xyz@def.com", "type": "work"}]'::jsonb)
)

select value->>'address' as address
from foo,
jsonb_array_elements(addresses)
where to_tsvector('simple', value->>'address') @@ to_tsquery('abc:*');

   address   
-------------
 abc@def.com
(1 row)
```